# Auto Load Plugin Hooks inside Must Use Plugin

Tags: plugins, multisite, actions, mu-plugins

I am creating a custom MU plugin to run on a multi-site network. I am working on a function that will dynamically include files containing additional action and filter hooks based on the active plugins for the current website being processed. The problem is, my function is not called when I visit a child site. Only the main site fires this event. How can I get it to execute the function regardless of the site I am on?

```
function my_plugin_autoload_plugin_hooks() {
    $active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
    // Include custom files from my plugin if they appear in the $active_plugin list.
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_autoload_plugin_hooks');
```

Comment: Where is the code above? What file? How is that piece of code loaded? What have you done to test the idea that the function doesn't fire? Have you tried a simple `wp_die('howdy');`, for example?

Comment: Are you trying to load WordPress plugins without activation?

Comment: The code lives in the wp-content/mu-plugins folder. I was using xdebug and saw my breakpoints being hit in the function on my main site but not for a child site.

Comment: I even tried just set a breakpoint at the very beginning of the plugin in the php file that sits directly in the mu-plugins folder and still didn't hit it on the child site. So it makes me think there is something wrong with mu-plugins running on a child site?

Comment: No, there isn't. I'm using that all the time with 40+ mu plugins in MS installations. Add an `exit( '<h1>HELLO!</h1>' );` to your plugin to see if it triggers. Else your setup (`wp-config.php` and the directories) will have to be shown in the question - [edit] please - because then only those, in theory, should be able to affect your setup.

Answer (score 1):

With Multisite, you need to use add_site_option/get_site_option instead of add_option/get_option.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option